# how do I create simple yes/no dialog in qgis python plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I'm making a QGIS plugin that processes a dataset. I started with pluginbuilder and have a GUI that allows me to set what to do.

As my plugin is making changes, when it detects a certain threshold of changes I want it to pop up a dialog with the old and new values and ask whether to apply changes or skip. How do I do that?

The basic structure so far:

```py
if abs(oldCount - newCount) > 10:
    ????
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [QMessageBox.question](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#question):

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui
reply = QMessageBox.question(self.iface.mainWindow(), 'Continue?', 
                 'Your message here', QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No)
if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
    #do something if yes
else:
    #do something if no
```

or in console:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui
reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(iface.mainWindow(), 'Continue?', 
                 'Your message here', QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
```

Comment: Worked great. One thing I ran into was the section of code I wanted to pop open the question was in a different module than the main file so I had to pass the iface on to the module.

Answer (score 0):

Maxim's answer is great, but now a little outdated. For console try:

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

promptReply = QMessageBox.question(iface.mainWindow(), 'Prompt', 'Click a button', QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No)
                 
if promptReply == QMessageBox.Yes:
    print("You clicked yes")
else:
    print("You clicked no")
```